# unable to insert data into sqlite database for android device

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

I've met an unknown error while inserting data into the database. The LogCat had been display "unable to insert data", however, the code that I've used is copied from another activity (which works).

weird enough, when I placed the code in the `onStart()` method, it works. but when I placed into my `onClick()`, it failed.

`onStart()`: <- not sure whether it's related to the error

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    dbopener = new DB_Route_ListOpener(this);

    try {

        dbopener.createDatabase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }//create database

    try {

        dbopener.openDatabase();

    }catch(SQLException sqle){

        throw sqle;

    }//open database

    // Configure the listview
    routeItems = new ArrayList<String>(dbopener.selectData(new String [] {"RouteName"}, null, null, null, null, null));

    routeListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,routeItems);
    routeListItem = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.mlt_route_list_route);
    routeListItem.setAdapter(routeListAdapter);
    routeListItem.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    dbopener.close();

}//onStart
```

`onClick()`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v == findViewById(R.id.mlt_route_btn_addroute))//add
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setMessage("Add name ?");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();

                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("RouteName", "test");
                dbopener.insertData(null, cv);

            }
        });//clear all data

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });//negative

        builder.create().show();
    }//if
```

my insert query:

```
public void insertData (String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values) {

    try
    {
        myDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE, nullColumnHack, values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error :","unable to insert data");
    }//catch

}//insertData
```

Comment: Put e.printStackTrace() in your 'insert query' catch block and then look at the actual failing exception - the exception that you get from the database insert will tell you what you did incorrectly. You've made the logcat output useless by consuming and hiding the exception.

Comment: @vam } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); Log.e("Error :","unable to insert data");
    }//catch

Comment: thanks zeetoobiker and vnshetty. because of you guys that i found the error and able to use the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `dbopener` as a global variable and move `dbopener.close();` from `OnStart()` to `OnDestroy()` since you closed the DB before you insert the data

Comment: thanks for your answer, as I didnt know i could put in onDestroy. I've been putting in onStop and always recieve error that the database is empty, therefore unable to end. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);` don`t use "this" inside any click listener , because it refer current view instead of parent view. Try to use className.this like as follows...

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(className.this);
```