# Android: Put SQL data into array

Tags: android, sql

i have two mehods, one to collect SQL data and one to put it into a listview.. it seems i can't get the array to form correctly in the SQL part so that it can be passed tot the listview.

SQL act:

```
public String[] getDataInArray() { // get data for list and return in array form
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columms = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME};
    String[] return_colums = null;

    Cursor c = currentdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columms, null, null, null, null, null);

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int rowcount = 0;

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
    {
        return_colums[rowcount] = c.getString(iName) + "," + c.getString(iRow);
        rowcount = rowcount + 1;
    }

    return return_colums;
}
```

And the listview act:

```
public ListView whiskeylist;
public String[] DataArryWhiskey;  

      @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Start db view of whiskey

    DBConfig whiskeyrows = new DBConfig(this);


    whiskeyrows.open();
    DataArryWhiskey = whiskeyrows.getDataInArray();
    whiskeyrows.close();

    Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    whiskeylist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listofWhiskey);
    whiskeylist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , DataArryWhiskey));


    // End db view of whiskey

}// end onCreate
```

I keeps on crashing, can anybody help met a bit? Thx in advance

Comment: If you post your logcat log it might help

Comment: If you need to pass the data to the listView, why didn't you use the SimpleCursorAdapter instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved return_colums defination and declaration.

```
public String[] getDataInArray() { // get data for list and return in array form
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String[] columms = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME};


Cursor c = currentdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columms, null, null, null, null, null);

int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
int rowcount = 0;
  String[] return_colums = new String[c.getCount()];
for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
{
    return_colums[rowcount] = c.getString(iName) + "," + c.getString(iRow);
    rowcount = rowcount + 1;
}

return return_colums;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `whiskeyrows.close();` from `onCreate()` to `onDestroy()`. More details in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558850/unable-to-insert-data-into-sqlite-database-for-android-device/8559208#8559208)

Comment: You need to put the whiskeyrows as global variale: <br/> `public String[] DataArryWhiskey; <br/>
DBConfig whiskeyrows;  <br/>
      @Override  <br/>
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  <br/>
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  <br/>
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  <br/>
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  <br/>
<br/>
    // Start db view of whiskey  <br/>

    whiskeyrows = new DBConfig(this);` <br/> If you need to pass the data to the listView, why didn't you use the SimpleCursorAdapter instead?

Comment: i am realy a noob on adroid programming, i would like to use a simple cursor but i don't know how to transfrom this into my situation. i alsow cant get the code to work with your extra comment.

Comment: Strange thing is that it dit work and i still get a returnmessage if i use a string instead of a array.

Comment: It is simple to use SimpleCursorAdapter. Just load your cursor, rows to display and the layout representing each row in the listView in the adapter (SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)) and set the adapter of your listView to this SimpleCursorAdapter. This is much simpler than your implementation.

Comment: Thx for the help i am going to read the tutorial http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html